# looking for a function to check if a string contains a floating point

Tags: c++

In C++ is there a function in a commonly used library to check if a string contains a floating point?

Everywhere I look for a solution to this people are writing their own functions to check if a string contains a floating point.  But I just think this problem is so common there must be a function already written into a library somewhere, for example the std library or Boost library.

I don't want to write my own function, because every time I think of examples where it won't work, for example here in Germany the decimal point and the thousand separators are swapped.  So Pi is 3,14 not 3.14 and a million is 1.000.000 and not 1,000,000 or sometimes people in Germany write these numbers the UK way of 3.14 or 1,000,000.

Comment: How about [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)? Does both conversion and validation.

Comment: @ArminMontigny -- writing a regular expression that matches the full C++ specification for floating-point constants is not a simple task.

Comment: @ArminMontigny -- there you will find **lots** of answers, most of which are wrong. Regular expressions almost always create more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0):

std lib has necessary methods. If string is convertible it does. If not It will return INF or NAN. Please read the page.

[std::stof,std::stod,std::stold](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)